# Deploy a J2ee web application (jboss server) on the web?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, hosting, web-deployment

so i've been searching on how can i deploy or host my web application j2ee for free, my web app is developed with EJBs and jboss server ,

the EC2 is expensive + i don't have a international visa card to complete my registrations , and the GEA do not support EJBs !

any suggestions please ?

Comment: This question is offtopic as it asks for a recommendation of an offsite resource, Google can help you.

Comment: i didn't find any thing in google , so i seeking for help here , Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com). Instead of JBoss you will find GlassFish and both are same in terms of functionality you want. As long as you remain with Java EE specs and create an EAR file you are just fine with any app server. Also Jelastic has a 14 days trial period with multiple hosts in different geo locations. Try that out as their web console is awesome and you can have load balancing features added. I recently moved to their platform and it is really great.
Surya

Comment: Here's an [example of EJB use in Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/docs/enterprise-javabeans).

Answer (score 0):

Tried looking up Google App Engine?  Though, I never used it, but read a bit about it. Do take a look and let me know if that helps :)

Here's the link.

[Google Web Apps home](https://appengine.google.com/)

Comment: As OP already stated, [GAE does not support EJB's](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava)

Comment: i'v mentionned google app engine as GEA in my question , it doesn't support the EJBs , and my web app j2ee is develloped using EJBs ..